# Is this usage of NSMutableString a memory leak?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, objective-c, memory-leaks

I'm currently using an instance variable that's an NSMutableString in a class which is a delegate for NSURLConnection. The variable is responsible for building a string of data that's returned from the delegate method:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

The string, 'foo', has a property set with retain on it. It is alloc'd in my classes init method very straight forward in this fashion:

```
dataString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
```

It is released in the classes dealloc method.

In connection:didReceiveData:, I use the var like this:

```
    NSString *tmpString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [dataString appendString:tmpString];
    [tmpString release];
```

Now this is where things get tricky. Since the class where I set the NSURLConnection delegate is a singleton (it mainly handles NSURL* type calls), I need to becareful with how I re-use my objects. Therefor, in my connectionDidFinishLoading: class I have the following:

```
   // cache away data currently in dataString.
[dataString release];
dataString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
```

Does that strategy of handling my dataString make your eyes bleed? Am I leaking memory? What can I do that's smarter?

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to ask us whether *every* [use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756908/is-this-an-objective-c-memory-leak) of an [object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722957/objective-c-cocoa-do-i-have-a-memory-leak-here) in your application is a memory leak?

[Read the documentation.](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/) Learn [the rules of object ownership](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html) and you will have your answer already, every time.

And if you suspect a leak, run Instruments' ObjectAlloc probe. [You've done this once already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726944/why-is-instruments-reporting-this-as-a-memory-leak), so clearly you know how. There's also [the leaks command](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/leaks.1.html).